# Unable to reach my H2 table from Matlab (but able from Java)

Tags: matlab, jdbc, h2

The following Java code works:

```
public class TestH2Schema {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

      Driver driver = new org.h2.Driver();
      Connection conn = driver.connect("jdbc:h2:file:D:/Users/Dims/Design/TESTS/SVHN_DB/db/svhn", null);

      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM IMAGE WHERE PATH='train/1.png';");
      while(rs.next()) {
         System.out.println(rs.getLong("ID"));
      }

      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();

   }
}
```

The following equivalent code in Matlab does not work:

```
driver = org.h2.Driver;
props = java.util.Properties;
conn = driver.connect('jdbc:h2:file:D:/Users/Dims/Design/TESTS/SVHN_DB/db/svhn', props);

stmt = conn.createStatement();
query = 'SELECT ID FROM IMAGE WHERE PATH=''train/1.png''';
rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while rs.next() 
    rs.getLong('ID')
end

rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

doesn't work causing exception

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table IMAGE not found; SQL statement:
```

**UPDATE**

If I query

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;'
```

I see a list of tables, but not mine ones. Looks like Matlab is somehow looking at different location or someting.

Answer (score 0):

matlab search in "MatlabDatabase"  (or another default data-source)
to use your own defined data-source you should declare it first

for example:

```
q1='use your_datasource';
q2='select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES';

exec(conn,q1);
exec(conn,q2);
```